# How to change python program to write output into a file?

Tags: python

I used the "pdf2txt.py" program which came as part of the pdfminer package in GitHub to try convert pdf file to text.As per the instruction , I ran the program by typing "python pdf2txt.py somefile.pdf" in the Mac OS terminal.The output was correctly generated and printed in the terminal itself. Now my question is this, how do I direct this output to a text file.I only know the bare basics of python and I am not able to figure out which line in the program actually prints the output and what needs to be changed to direct the same into a .txt file?

```
import argparse
import logging
import six
import sys
import pdfminer.settings
pdfminer.settings.STRICT = False
import pdfminer.high_level
import pdfminer.layout
from pdfminer.image import ImageWriter


def extract_text(files=[], outfile='-',
        _py2_no_more_posargs=None,  # Bloody Python2 needs a shim
        no_laparams=False, all_texts=None, detect_vertical=None, # LAParams
        word_margin=None, char_margin=None, line_margin=None, boxes_flow=None, # LAParams
        output_type='text', codec='utf-8', strip_control=False,
        maxpages=0, page_numbers=None, password="", scale=1.0, rotation=0,
        layoutmode='normal', output_dir=None, debug=False,
        disable_caching=False, **other):
if _py2_no_more_posargs is not None:
    raise ValueError("Too many positional arguments passed.")
if not files:
    raise ValueError("Must provide files to work upon!")

# If any LAParams group arguments were passed, create an LAParams object and
# populate with given args. Otherwise, set it to None.
if not no_laparams:
    laparams = pdfminer.layout.LAParams()
    for param in ("all_texts", "detect_vertical", "word_margin", "char_margin", "line_margin", "boxes_flow"):
        paramv = locals().get(param, None)
        if paramv is not None:
            setattr(laparams, param, paramv)
else:
    laparams = None

imagewriter = None
if output_dir:
    imagewriter = ImageWriter(output_dir)

if output_type == "text" and outfile != "-":
    for override, alttype in (  (".htm", "html"),
                                (".html", "html"),
                                (".xml", "xml"),
                                (".tag", "tag") ):
        if outfile.endswith(override):
            output_type = alttype

if outfile == "-":
    outfp = sys.stdout
    if outfp.encoding is not None:
        codec = 'utf-8'
else:
    outfp = open(outfile, "wb")


for fname in files:
    with open(fname, "rb") as fp:
        pdfminer.high_level.extract_text_to_fp(fp, **locals())
return outfp


def maketheparser():
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__, add_help=True)
parser.add_argument("files", type=str, default=None, nargs="+", help="File to process.")
parser.add_argument("-d", "--debug", default=False, action="store_true", help="Debug output.")
parser.add_argument("-p", "--pagenos", type=str, help="Comma-separated list of page numbers to parse. Included for legacy applications, use --page-numbers for more idiomatic argument entry.")
parser.add_argument("--page-numbers", type=int, default=None, nargs="+", help="Alternative to --pagenos with space-separated numbers; supercedes --pagenos where it is used.")
parser.add_argument("-m", "--maxpages", type=int, default=0, help="Maximum pages to parse")
parser.add_argument("-P", "--password", type=str, default="", help="Decryption password for PDF")
parser.add_argument("-o", "--outfile", type=str, default="-", help="Output file (default \"-\" is stdout)")
parser.add_argument("-t", "--output_type", type=str, default="text", help="Output type: text|html|xml|tag (default is text)")
parser.add_argument("-c", "--codec", type=str, default="utf-8", help="Text encoding")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--scale", type=float, default=1.0, help="Scale")
parser.add_argument("-A", "--all-texts", default=None, action="store_true", help="LAParams all texts")
parser.add_argument("-V", "--detect-vertical", default=None, action="store_true", help="LAParams detect vertical")
parser.add_argument("-W", "--word-margin", type=float, default=None, help="LAParams word margin")
parser.add_argument("-M", "--char-margin", type=float, default=None, help="LAParams char margin")
parser.add_argument("-L", "--line-margin", type=float, default=None, help="LAParams line margin")
parser.add_argument("-F", "--boxes-flow", type=float, default=None, help="LAParams boxes flow")
parser.add_argument("-Y", "--layoutmode", default="normal", type=str, help="HTML Layout Mode")
parser.add_argument("-n", "--no-laparams", default=False, action="store_true", help="Pass None as LAParams")
parser.add_argument("-R", "--rotation", default=0, type=int, help="Rotation")
parser.add_argument("-O", "--output-dir", default=None, help="Output directory for images")
parser.add_argument("-C", "--disable-caching", default=False, action="store_true", help="Disable caching")
parser.add_argument("-S", "--strip-control", default=False, action="store_true", help="Strip control in XML mode")
return parser


# main


def main(args=None):

P = maketheparser()
A = P.parse_args(args=args)

if A.page_numbers:
    A.page_numbers = set([x-1 for x in A.page_numbers])
if A.pagenos:
    A.page_numbers = set([int(x)-1 for x in A.pagenos.split(",")])

imagewriter = None
if A.output_dir:
    imagewriter = ImageWriter(A.output_dir)

if six.PY2 and sys.stdin.encoding:
    A.password = A.password.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)

if A.output_type == "text" and A.outfile != "-":
    for override, alttype in (  (".htm",  "html"),
                                (".html", "html"),
                                (".xml",  "xml" ),
                                (".tag",  "tag" ) ):
        if A.outfile.endswith(override):
            A.output_type = alttype

if A.outfile == "-":
    outfp = sys.stdout
    if outfp.encoding is not None:
        # Why ignore outfp.encoding? :-/ stupid cathal?
        A.codec = 'utf-8'
else:
    outfp = open(A.outfile, "wb")

## Test Code
outfp = extract_text(**vars(A))
outfp.close()
return 0


if __name__ == '__main__': sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: A casual reading of the code shows a `"-o", "--outfile",` option which you might want to considering using first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the inputs.
I added a line

```
sys.stdout=open("somefile.txt","w")
```

right before the line

```
outfp=sys.stdout.
```

worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
python pdf2txt.py somefile.pd > pdf_text.txt
```

Comment: Yes..This worked great! Thank you! But I would prefer something that would do exactly this within the code itself.Any idea?

Comment: You can do it using subprocess module or using os.system(). If this answer helped you, please upvote.